# golang write struct as raw data

Tags: linux, go, io, low-level-io

I am working on a new type of database, using GO. One of the things I would like to do is have a distributed disk so that I can distribute queries over multiple machines (think Pi type architectures). This means building my own structures on raw disk.

My challenge is that I can't find a GO package that will let me write N bytes from a pointer to a structure. All the IO packages limit the access to []byte slices.

That's nice for protection, but if I have to buffer everything through a byte array via some form of encoding it will slow down the access to a specific object.

Anyone got any idea on how to do raw IO? Or am I going to have to handle GOBs as my unit of IO and suffer the penalty for encoding/decoding?

Answer (score 3):

Big warning first: **don't do it: it is neither safe nor portable**

For a given struct, you can reflect over it to figure out the in-memory size of the actual struct, then unsafely cast it to a `[]byte` using `unsafe`.

eg: `(*[in-mem size]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&mystruct))`

This will give you something C-ish with absolutely no safety guarantees or portability.

I'll quote the [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_unsafe):

> A package using unsafe must be vetted manually for type safety and may
>   not be portable.

You can find a lot more details in this [Go and Memory layout](https://syslog.ravelin.com/go-and-memory-layout-6ef30c730d51) post, including all the steps you need to unsafely treat structs as just bytes.

Overall, it's fascinating to examine how Go functions on a low level, but this is absolutely the wrong thing to do in your case. Any real data infrastructure will need storage logic way more complicated than just dumping in-memory structs to disk anyway.

Comment: Oh,  I do agree. For reference, I used to write device drives on VMS in days long ago, and I know that there is a lot more than dumping raw values.I was involved in writing a driver to make a Cray XMP appear as a peripheral on the VAX. I miss my low level stuff! 

I just wanted to get started on some simple test cases and hit a brick wall. I know it's all 'unsafe', but then I am writing for a specific use case, on specific hardware configuration. Portability is not my issue. 

Thanks for the reply, and so fast.

Comment: The portability is important, btw.  The size of those structures will change depending on 32 or 64-bit architecture, and the ordering and padding of those structures is not guaranteed to be the same between Go versions or the target OS/architecture for the compilation.  This really is a terribly bug-prone practice.  There's a _reason_ Go doesn't let you muck with memory directly or do C things like pointer arithmetic.  It causes super brittle and buggy code that's insanely difficult to debug.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you cannot do raw IO of a Go struct (i.e. memdump). This is because many things in Go contain pointers, and the actual data is not contiguous in memory.

For example, a struct like this:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
}
```

contains a string, which in turn [contains a pointer](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StringHeader) to the bytes of the string. A raw memdump would only dump the pointer.

The solution is serialization. This is never free, although some implementations do a pretty good job.

The closest to what you are describing is something like [go-memdump](https://github.com/alexflint/go-memdump), but I wouldn't recommend it for production.

Otherwise, I recommend looking at a [performant serialization technique](https://github.com/alecthomas/go_serialization_benchmarks). (Go's gob encoding is not the best.)

Answer (score 0):

> ...Or am I going to have to handle GOBs as my unit of IO and suffer the penalty for encoding/decoding?

Just use GOBs. 
Premature optimization is the root of all evil.